# thread approach to process indipendent sets of data

Tags: c, multithreading, sensors

I have a set of data coming one at a time every T ms (e.g. data coming from some hardware). When a certain number M of this samples is gathered, I want to process them and print the output on video, which might take a "long" time, so that I can't stop reading, doing this and then continue reading otherwise I'll miss part of the data coming during my processing.

I can't use shared resources either I think, because if I continue reading while processing the array of M cells I previously filled, I'll complete my process with a modified data structure.
I think I can't use a second one to add the new data coming during computation because the computation might take than M*T ms, so that I'll need a third and so on.

So I thought that a solution to this might be detaching a thread when I have the M data samples so that I'll not stop reading and if the process of the first thread takes more than M*T, a new thread will be detached handling the new set of M samples. Something like this

```
samples = 0;
...

while(1){
  data[samples++] = get_sample();
  if(samples == M)
  {
    pthread_t t_id;
    float data_copy[M];
  
    for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i) data_copy[i] = data[i];
    pthread_create(&t_id, NULL, veryLongMathFunction, (void*)data_copy);
    samples = 0;
  }
  sleep(...) // I'm not using a sleep, just to give the idea that this action is performed every T ms
}
```

I'm not sure if this approach is correct though. Actually, I suspect that it contains plenty of problems. So my questions are:

- is this correct ?
- is there any smarter way of solving the original problem ?
- do I need to manually cancel the threads or they'll die themselves when the processing is done?
- each thread is independent, but how can I synch them in order to print in the correct order ?
  If you prefer C++ instead of C, it will be helpful as well.

Comment: This looks bad because `data_copy` is a non-static local variable of a block that will soon exited after creating a thread and it is not guaranteed that it is available until access for that data from the thread is done.

Comment: Copying data and starting threads are expensive operations. It would be more efficient to create and fill a new array each time and then hand it off to a thread for processing, and to use a thread pool.

Comment: @Ron thanks, I removed the C++ tag. I don't know how to rewrite my question in Q&A style, but what I was asking is how to fix that piece of code in order to do properly what I described at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

> is this correct ?

No - you do not keep the thread handle, which means you can't join it. Since `pthread_join` allows you to retrieve the `void*` return value, that return value must be stored somewhere, and you're leaking it.

If you don't want to keep the handle and join it, you should call `pthread_detach` to avoid this leak.

You also need to avoid having a single sample array being (over-)written and processed at the same time. Details below.

> is there any smarter way of solving the original problem ?

If you're concerned about performance, you should *never* create threads on the fly. It isn't cheap, so create a background thread (or a pool of them) up-front and have them sleep until there's work to do.

If you have a pool of threads, you typically want one thread per core available to do actual work (or per instruction pipeline, if you have hyperthreading available and enabled). In this case, you need to write some way to recombine their results in the correct order.

You can also pre-allocate sample arrays, since they're fixed size: one per background thread plus one working instance currently being written. You can just keep them in a circular buffer, so when the working one fills up, you simply notify your thread pool and start writing to the next. If the next is still being processed, you're back to having a problem: you probably can't do much better than keep overwriting the current working buffer until the next one is done. This will at least collapse incoming updates until your thread pool catches up.

> do I need to manually cancel the threads or they'll die themselves when the processing is done?

The thread will exit when `veryLongMathFunction` returns (although as described above its return value will be leaked in the current code).

> each thread is independent, but how can I synch them in order to print in the correct order ? If you prefer C++ instead of C, it will be helpful as well.

If you have a circular buffer of sample buffers as described above, you just need a way to mark their state (writing/processing/ready), and you output them in order. If you organize your data differently, you need to write some other way of keeping them in sequence.

If you prefer C++, you should be using [`<thread>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) instead of pthreads anyway, but the code and data layout don't change much. You could use `packaged_task` and futures to reduce some of the boilerplate, but should probably still prefer a thread pool over just using `async` if you're worried about performance.